# Kendo Grid: issue with DataType based Filter

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have one data table and it contains columns of different datatype(e.g String, Date Time, Boolean and etc..), Following is code snippet that I have written in .cshtml file

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ViewResultTable)
.Name("Grid").Columns(columns =>
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in Model.ViewResultTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(column => column.ColumnName != "XYZ"))
    {
        columns.Bound(typeof(DateTime) ,column.ColumnName).Title(column.ColumnName).Filterable(true).Width(120);        
    }
})
.Pageable(pageable => pageable
    .PageSizes(new[] { 15, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500 })
    .Messages(a => a.ItemsPerPage(""))
    .PreviousNext(false)
    .ButtonCount(5)
)
.Filterable(f => f.Extra(false))
.Groupable()
.ClientDetailTemplateId("template123")
.DataSource(
    dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(15)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    )
.TableHtmlAttributes(new { @class= "grid" })
)
```

It takes all the type as string even defined type as "Date" or "Number". Does anyone having idea how to fix?